# Number of texted processed = 1 when it should = 4 (function to process documents)

Tags: python, r, gensim

I have this data (the data is generated in R) and I use the `reticulate` package to port over to Python. The problem is with my Python code.

R code :

```
text <- c("Because I could not stop for Death -",
          "He kindly stopped for me -",
          "The Carriage held but just Ourselves -",
          "and Immortality")

ID <- c(1,2,3,4)    
df <- data.frame(cbind(ID, text))
library(reticulate)

df_py <- r_to_py(df)
repl_python()
```

Python code :

```
import gensim
LabeledSentence1 = gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument
all_content_data = []
j = 0
for em in r.df_py['text'].values:
  all_content_data.append(LabeledSentence1(em,[j]))
j+=1
print('Number of texts processed: ', j)
```

Note: The `r.df_py['text']` is a "special" function which calls R data, it can be changed to `df_py['text']` if just using Python.

The data is supposed to process the documents but when I print it says `Number of texts processed:  1` when it should say `Number of texts processed:  4`. I just don't know where I am going wrong in that function. My data is a data frame and in each row I have a unique "book" all the text of that book is in one cell and I want to process that cell.

Comment: Your `j += 1` is outside the loop, it can't be incremented. Hence stays at 1.

Comment: Ohh so its an indentation problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your `j += 1` is outside the loop, hence can't be incremented. Therefore it stays at 1. Put it inside the for-loop's indentation:

```
for em in r.df_py['text'].values:
    all_content_data.append(LabeledSentence1(em,[j]))
    j+=1
```

Comment: Alternatively, the OP could avoid having to manually define and increment `j` by using `for (n, m) in enumerate(r.df_py['text'].values):`

Comment: Cool! I am glad it did. Please don't forget to accept the most useful answer - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your increment statement is simply not indented correctly therefore it is outside the loop
Here is how it should be:

```
for em in r.df_py['text'].values:
   all_content_data.append(LabeledSentence1(em,[j]))
   j+=1
```

When first switching from Java to python I made that mistake a lot so don't feel alone :)

Comment: Always glad to help :)